# Which video stabilizer keeps the horizon?

Tags: windows, video, video-editing, media-converter, file-converter

Which video conversion software tracks a reference picture as being horizontal and rotates all other frames of a video accordingly?

Most video stabilizers don't rotate the video around 90 degrees or more. The software I am looking for should always obey the horizon based on image patterns.

It should be able to deal with GoPro footage, i.e. fisheye, and needs to work on Windows.

Comment: Do you have an OS requirement?

Comment: @RockPaperLizard I updated the tags